# Invalid gemspec when trying to exec rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, snort

After executing command:

```
 sudo bundle exec rake snorby:setup
```

I get the error:

```
 Invalid .gemspec format in '/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/dm-active_model-1.2.1.gemspec
WARNING:  #<ArgumentError: Illformed requirement ["#<YAML::Syck::DefaultKey:0x7f8cb7e8a1c0> 1.2.3"]>
```

I am pretty new to ruby, just trying to install a program. Anyone have any ideas on this?

```
greenlantern@greenlantern:~/snorby/snorby$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what has been said I'd assume that you use rvm, rbenv or similar, which are not loaded when you use `sudo`. So in sudo, you get ruby 1.8.
Why do you use sudo anyway? Try to run just `bundle exec rake snorby:setup`, without sudo.

Answer (score 0):

What version of ruby are you using? Snorby only supports ruby >= 1.9.2. Hope this helps.

Comment: The '1.8' in `Invalid .gemspec format in '/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/dm-active_model-1.2.1.gemspec` indicates that you're not using 1.9.3